# Emailjs Not Working with React App but Testing Correctly

Tags: reactjs, email, netlify

React App & EmailJS Not Sending Emails

Hi, hope all is well. I recently began implementing emails into my React app. I used a contact form another blogs contact form and I think it may be outdated. I have tried updating some things with the emailjs documentation, but I'm still getting nothing. The test emails that come from emailjs work just fine, but not from the my sites form.

The error from the browser is:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import "./style.css";
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import { meta } from "../../content_option";
import { Container, Row, Col, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { contactConfig } from "../../content_option";

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({
    email: "",
    name: "",
    message: "",
    loading: false,
    show: false,
    alertmessage: "",
    variant: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormdata({ loading: true });

    const templateParams = {
      from_name: formData.email,
      user_name: formData.name,
      to_name: contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL,
      message: formData.message,
    };

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
        process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
        templateParams,
        process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          setFormdata({
            loading: false,
            alertmessage: "SUCCESS! ,Thankyou for your messege",
            variant: "success",
            show: true,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
          setFormdata({
            alertmessage: `Faild to send!,${error.text}`,
            variant: "danger",
            show: true,
          });
          document.getElementsByClassName("co_alert")[0].scrollIntoView();
        }
      );
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormdata({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Container>
        <Helmet>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>{meta.title} | Contact</title>
          <meta name="description" content={meta.description} />
        </Helmet>
        <Row className="mb-5 mt-3 pt-md-3">
          <Col lg="8">
            <h1 className="display-4 mb-4">Contact Me</h1>
            <hr className="t_border my-4 ml-0 text-left" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row className="sec_sp">
          <Col lg="12">
            <Alert
              //show={formData.show}
              variant={formData.variant}
              className={`rounded-0 co_alert ${formData.show ? "d-block" : "d-none"
                }`}
              onClose={() => setFormdata({ show: false })}
              dismissible
            >
              <p className="my-0">{formData.alertmessage}</p>
            </Alert>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="5" className="mb-5">
            <h3 className="color_sec py-4">Get in touch</h3>
            <address>
              <strong>Email:</strong>{" "}
              <a href={`mailto:${contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL}`}>
                {contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL}
              </a>
              <br />
              <br />
              {contactConfig.hasOwnProperty("YOUR_FONE") ? (
                <p>
                  <strong>Phone:</strong> {contactConfig.YOUR_FONE}
                </p>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </address>
            <p>{contactConfig.description}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="7" className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="contact__form w-100">
              <Row>
                <Col lg="6" className="form-group">
                  <input
                    className="form-control"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={formData.name || ""}
                    type="text"
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col lg="6" className="form-group">
                  <input
                    className="form-control rounded-0"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    type="email"
                    value={formData.email || ""}
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <textarea
                className="form-control rounded-0"
                id="message"
                name="message"
                placeholder="Message"
                rows="5"
                value={formData.message}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              ></textarea>
              <br />
              <Row>
                <Col lg="12" className="form-group">
                  <button className="btn ac_btn" type="submit">
                    {formData.loading ? "Sending..." : "Send"}
                  </button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <div className={formData.loading ? "loading-bar" : "d-none"}></div>
    </HelmetProvider>
  );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

https://github.com/ToniTepes/tonitepes.github.io

Comment: Anyone? Should be pretty simple...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think I can be more clear. I need my React App to send me emails using emailjs. When the formed is filled out and the person using it hits 'send' the page just loads and loads and does nothing. The test emails from emailjs work fine, but not the form. Sorry, I don't know what else to say or how else to explain it.

Comment: Exactly what I need is emails sent to me, from the form on this website: 
https://peaceful-caramel-4fb6dc.netlify.app/contact

Comment: Okay, I have taken a look at your code & the contact form. First off, I didn't receive the error in the browser console you're describing. However a quick search explains that's often related to browser extension, so I recommend you try use the website while disabling all extensions & in incognito mode. Second, there is an issue with your code, particularly in the part where it uses `emailJS` to send emails. Please edit your answer to include the `contact/index.js` for me to help you better.

Comment: I did launch it in a incognito browser with no extensions and it did the same thing. 
No problem, I will edit it now. Sorry I thought you would be able to see it in my github. One sec. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone else that can help with this?

Comment: I'm still having this issue if anyone can help. I would really like to get my sight live so that I can start making some money. Help please.

Comment: Hey Antonio - sorry not replying, I got busy. However, I think your issue might have something to do with not using on this line `emailjs.sendForm(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID, process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID, templateParams, process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY)` in place of the `templateParams` a direct reference to the form itself. You can achieve this by using React `useRef()` hook.

Comment: Was the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you're not referencing the form element directly in the `emailjs` function.

A edit to your code would have it be:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import * as emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import "./style.css";
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import { meta } from "../../content_option";
import { Container, Row, Col, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { contactConfig } from "../../content_option";

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef(null);
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({
    email: "",
    name: "",
    message: "",
    loading: false,
    show: false,
    alertmessage: "",
    variant: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormdata({ loading: true });

    const templateParams = {
      from_name: formData.email,
      user_name: formData.name,
      to_name: contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL,
      message: formData.message,
    };

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
        process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
        form.current,
        process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          setFormdata({
            loading: false,
            alertmessage: "SUCCESS! ,Thankyou for your messege",
            variant: "success",
            show: true,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
          setFormdata({
            alertmessage: `Faild to send!,${error.text}`,
            variant: "danger",
            show: true,
          });
          document.getElementsByClassName("co_alert")[0].scrollIntoView();
        }
      );
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormdata({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Container>
        <Helmet>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>{meta.title} | Contact</title>
          <meta name="description" content={meta.description} />
        </Helmet>
        <Row className="mb-5 mt-3 pt-md-3">
          <Col lg="8">
            <h1 className="display-4 mb-4">Contact Me</h1>
            <hr className="t_border my-4 ml-0 text-left" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row className="sec_sp">
          <Col lg="12">
            <Alert
              //show={formData.show}
              variant={formData.variant}
              className={`rounded-0 co_alert ${formData.show ? "d-block" : "d-none"
                }`}
              onClose={() => setFormdata({ show: false })}
              dismissible
            >
              <p className="my-0">{formData.alertmessage}</p>
            </Alert>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="5" className="mb-5">
            <h3 className="color_sec py-4">Get in touch</h3>
            <address>
              <strong>Email:</strong>{" "}
              <a href={`mailto:${contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL}`}>
                {contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL}
              </a>
              <br />
              <br />
              {contactConfig.hasOwnProperty("YOUR_FONE") ? (
                <p>
                  <strong>Phone:</strong> {contactConfig.YOUR_FONE}
                </p>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </address>
            <p>{contactConfig.description}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="7" className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="contact__form w-100">
              <Row>
                <Col lg="6" className="form-group">
                  <input
                    className="form-control"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={formData.name || ""}
                    type="text"
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col lg="6" className="form-group">
                  <input
                    className="form-control rounded-0"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    type="email"
                    value={formData.email || ""}
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <textarea
                className="form-control rounded-0"
                id="message"
                name="message"
                placeholder="Message"
                rows="5"
                value={formData.message}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              ></textarea>
              <br />
              <Row>
                <Col lg="12" className="form-group">
                  <button className="btn ac_btn" type="submit">
                    {formData.loading ? "Sending..." : "Send"}
                  </button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <div className={formData.loading ? "loading-bar" : "d-none"}></div>
    </HelmetProvider>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi @Abdulrahman Ali after using the code above, and running in a private browser with no extensions the same thing happens. When you push the send button, the page just continuously loads and gave me an error in the console.

Comment: ```
react-dom.production.min.js:106 Uncaught The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form
Dr @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
ss @ react-dom.production.min.js:274
Pe @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
Wr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109
qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
$t @ react-dom.production.min.js:73
```

Comment: @AntonioFoushee - so I made a mistake in the answer and passed `form.current` to ref prop instead of the `form` alone. Please edit your code according to the answer, I have updated it. It hopefully would work now! :)

Comment: the site build on Netlify is failing with this 

`templateParams is assigned a value but never used`

 Should I delete or comment out the const block? Also, do you know if I need to include the IDs in the content_options file? 

Thanks again, sorry this is a pain.

Comment: @AntonioFoushee - the 'error' msg you're seeing is just a warning & it isn't what's causing the Netlify build to stop/fail. I don't know what you mean by the `const block` part but regarding the IDs in the `content_options` file, then yes, you indeed need to include the related IDs from emailJS dashboard to have it working.

Comment: This is the const block I am referring to. 

```
const templateParams = {
      from_name: formData.email,
      user_name: formData.name,
      to_name: contactConfig.YOUR_EMAIL,
      message: formData.message,
    };
```
This is where I believe the build error `templateParams is assigned a value but never used` is coming from. It happened when I replaced `form.current` with `templateParas`

Comment: @AntonioFoushee - Yes, I know, but this isn't an error, it's just a warning because `templateParams` is an unused variable, it isn't what making the build fail. Again, like I said in my previous comment, check the relevant IDs required to make EmailJS work. They provided to you by EmailJS & you find them in their dashboard.

Comment: @AntonioFoushee - This the `content_options` file and in [this](https://imgur.com/ORWFml7l.png), you're not setting the appropriate values for the relevant IDs, please fill & your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I have been moving. So I used a .env to hide my IDs, but I promise that they are all correct. I have checked them several times. My contentjs looks like ```YOUR_SERVICE_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
    YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
    YOUR_USER_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY,
``` and my contactjs looks like ```emailjs
      .sendForm(
        process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
        process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
        form.current,
        process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY
      )```

Comment: But because of the error it will not build or deploy on Netlify. Locally, yes, it runs fine and just alerts me of the templateParams error. But deploying to Netlify does not work. It will not build, because of that same error, and if it doesn't build, it wont deploy. Netlify says ```We couldn’t deploy your site. Check out our Build docs for tips on troubleshooting your build```  When I add tepmplateParams and push to Netlify, it does not fail to build. It builds just fine and says `Published` instead of `failed`